# Cors on one route but not the other with Vue

Tags: vue.js, lumen

Been trying to figure out what is wrong for days without luck.
I have my own API on my server, then I try to connect with Postman and everything works fine. I try to connect with VueJS and everything is fine too.

I created a new end-point, and no matter what I do, I always keep getting a cors error. Below screenshot is a HTTP call on line 30, and one on line 31 to the exact same API.

One works, the other does not. Can anyone tell me what is wrong and -or how to find out what is wrong?

I want my API to be accessible from outside by anyone who has valid credentials.

I am using Lumen for my API and VueJS for my front-end.

Working call:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhPgG.png)

Not working call:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7dqE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data in Json format, i guess.
In working one, you are sending header **Content-Type** : **application/json**
That's why it's working

In other, you are sending header **Content-Type** : **text-plain/html**
Which isn't applicable, That's why it's not working